# Django Non-Managed Models - Building Query set from JSON Data

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to have model that don't need to be created in database as table but use data from other sources like json files and other model objects. So I am using Non-Managed Model. This model is being created dynamically as described [here in the docs](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels)

Now Let me explain how I want to create the fields in this `non-managed model`. I have a json file that defines what fields should be in model, Let's call it `contact-model.json`. fields in this json file are mapped to django fields and dynamic model is created. This part is done.

```
{
    'model_name': 'Contact'
    'fields': {
        'name': 'CharField',
        'email': 'EmailField' 
    }
}
```

Now I have model that is storing all data related to above `contact-model.json`. Code for that model is given below

```
class GenericAnswer(models.Model):
    answer = JSONField()
    model = CharField(default='Contact', max_length=30)
```

And value of that asnwer would be

```
{
    'name': 'Adil Malik',
    'email': 'sample@email.com'
}
```

What I want to do is that when I fetch `Contact.objects.all()`, It should return objects fetching from `GenericAnswer` based on model name, in this onctext, it is **Contact**.

Can I do it. If Yes, Plese Explain How ????

Comment: You need to describe your own `class` that behaves like `models.Model`, there is no builtin solution that satisfies your needs.

Comment: @vishes_shell  have done that, I am able to create model Class. I just don't know how can I map json to queryset.